# Slim isLoggedIn small middleware to redirect user if already logged in

Tags: php, slim

I am using Slim php, I created this function to determine if the user is logged in and prevent user to access the route if not.

```
$isLoggedIn = function() {
    return function () {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
            $app->redirect('login');
        }
    };
};
```

This works well with:

```
$app->get('/dashboard', $isLoggedIn() ,function() use ($app){
    $app->render('member.php');
})->name('member');
```

But I want that function also to work with the login route, so i tweaked it a bit

```
$isLoggedIn = function() {
    return function () {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
            $app->redirect('login');
        } else {
            $app->redirect('member');
        }
    };
};
```

As you can see, it'll loop endlessly on the member route, because he is already logged in. What approach should I do? should I just make another function to use in the login route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and most consistent solution here will be to use hooks. Hook your access control function like this:

```
$app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', function () use ($app) {
    if(!loggedIn) {
        $app->redirect('login');
    }
});
```

Now, your login action can look like this:

```
$app->get('/login', function() use ($app){
    $app->render('login.php', array('loggedIn' => true));
});
```

And on your template if $loggedIn == true, you just show logout button.

I'm not 100% sure about hook name, you should check docs:

http://docs.slimframework.com/#Hooks-Overview